# Error R - t.test

Tags: r

I am attempting to run a t.test on this data (to 'test' whether males really do drink more than females). I am not entirely sure what I am doing haha - I think I have worked out how to do t.test but now an error is coming up saying:

`"Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length".`

`x` is males, `y` is females - are these even the correct `x` and `y` values?

My full code:

```
surv <- read.csv("classsurvey.csv")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(surv, aes(y=UnitsAlcohol, x=Gender)) + geom_boxplot()
#This boxplot shows that males drink more units of alcohol than females.
t.test(??Male,??Female,paired=TRUE)
```

Comment: I doubt you want a paired t-test when comparing males and females (see http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf for appropriate scenarios for using a paired test). That could be the immediate issue. Also, I think your code is wrong - `??Male` or any variable starting with question marks looks wrong. You should be referencing your `surv` dataset in some way when doing your `t.test` - `t.test(surv$UnitsAlcohol[surv$gender=="Male"], surv$UnitsAlcohol[surv$gender=="Female"])` or `t.test(UnitsAlcohol ~ gender, data = surv)`

Answer (score 0):

In your t.test you have used `paired = TRUE` which actually isn't the case. We use `paired = TRUE` when the subject is the same i.e. the same person is being twice. For example = reflex to stimulus before and after taking the drug. In this case the subjects are completely different.

Also, the main test that you want to run is on UnitsAlcohol and not on Gender.

Try this code:

```
t.test(UnitsAlchohol ~ Gender, paired = FALSE, data = surv)
```